# Volley - wrong url or network connection error?

Tags: android, connection, android-volley

How can I tell the difference between wrong URL (wrong server address) and offline network?
In both cases I get communication VolleyError which is "instanceof NoConnectionError" and "instanceof NetworkError"

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by asking this:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)    
        mCtx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfoconnectivityManager
                                                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null &&  
        activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```